# Filling in spaces for entries...

Tags: channel-entries

Like, say if you require 10 entries in your Channel limit but there is only 4. Is there a way of filling in these 'spaces' with alternate text or html?

I've found a plugin called [Filler](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/filler) which does exactly this but it doesn't work in my case as I'm filtering the results through a couple of custom field searches via another plugin.

Anyone had to address something like this? Or any suggestions of another way to get alternate content into a channel entries loop as described above? Would use an if conditional but that won't work so is basically a way of faking an entry or entries that's needed.

Comment: I really don't know why you'd want to do that. Content should always be relevant or it's better off not being there at all. What's the use case? You'll need to provide more specifics for someone to be able to provide an answer.

Comment: I have a channel which is shows for appointments: 10am, 11am etc.

If someone books an appointment at 10 say, it will show 1 entry for 10. I want it to show that entry for 10 saying BOOKED (i.e. a client submitted entry) and three others for 11, 12 etc which say NOT BOOKED because no-one has submitted them. 

No way of getting that in my case other than this way as conditionals can't test against what isn't there to show alternate content.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a form of daily calendar than I'd look to handle the display purely in the front-end templates so that each hour slot is laid out in full. You can then just loop through the channel entries for that channel and test on a single conditional to see if it has either been *booked* or is *vacant*. This can be either be a status message on the channel entry or checking the existence of a particular field for details of that appointment.

In this case you wouldn't need any filler content as it's handled by the template itself and you're just adding a status to it.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing but I can't get the either/or conditional working to test the logic. Basically the results are being returned from a search on custom fields. There’s two channels: available and booked and custom fields are the same on each: 10, 11, 12 etc being the timeslots.

Here’s the problem: 10 (for example) has to be present in the ‘available’ channel as a default, as do all the other timeslots - 10 is always there in the ‘available’ channel but only there in the ‘booked’ channel when someone books it.

Comment: Ie when someone books 10 then entry in ‘booked’ channel is shown & entry 10 in ‘available’ hidden.


Set it up via a conditional but no way to stop returning both 10s. Tried many combinations but not found logic to do this:


**If 10 in ‘channel booked’ exists -> show entry
If no entry for 10 exists in ‘channel booked’ then show entry for 10 in ‘channel available’**


Now I'm trying to lose the ‘available’ channel and just fill in the ‘available’ slot if no results for the custom field. Ideally the conditional would be the way to go but I don’t think it’s possible. Or is it?